# Java EJB Lookup Fails in Glassfish

Tags: java, maven, junit, glassfish

I am facing issues looking up beans in the embedded EJBContainer for Glassfish. I have tried multiple things in an a standlone JUnit test the JDNI works. However, when I run through Apache Maven the full set of tests the JNDI cannot be found. I have been on this issue since some days and I can't find anything to fix it. EJB version is 3.1.

I have looked into resources such as: https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html and https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-12298

by trying

```
@Stateless
@Local
@EJB(name="java:global/SharedBean", beanInterface=SharedRemote.class)
public class SharedBean implements SharedRemote { ... }
```

However, I have tried lookup at "java:global/SharedBean" and it works in a standlone JUnit test. However, as soon as I run it through Apache Maven the full set of tests it throws

```
javax.naming.NamingException
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maven doesn't have a JNDI lookup service like you do when JBOSS is up.  You'll have to mock up the bean lookup or find a way to let JUnit run JBOSS.  This was a big motivation behind Rod Johnson creating Spring: POJOs are so much easier to test.

Comment: I am not using JBoss. I am using Glassfish and there is a API that creates a local instance of the EJBContainer by calling EJBContainer.createContainer().

Comment: I have used this example of the EJBContainer http://www.hascode.com/2011/09/java-ee-6-development-using-the-maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin/